# Why is UIBezierPath faster than CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, calayer, lag, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have been experimenting with drawing maps.  I drew a map of the United States as a series of UIBezierPath's (one path for each state - converted an SVG file with PaintCode).  At the same time I was working with CAShapeLayer's and was amazed at how fast they were.  I decided to convert the UIBezierPath to a CAShapeLayer.  It ended up being extremely slow.  The view would stutter even when I rotated the device.  Does anyone know why it would be so slow?  It seems that whenever I fill a view with too many CAShapeLayer's it slows the application down tremendously.

This is not a code specific problem, I am just wondering if there are limitations to the amount of CALayer's you can use in an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CAShapeLayer` is mostly used to create shapes that you would animate. So when you use it each modification is animated. I don't know `UIBezierPath` but `CAShapeLayer` also use antialiasing during rasterization and that would require offscreen rendering that is an expensive task.

Answer (score 0):

offscreen rendering includes
shouldRasterize（光栅化）
masks（遮罩）
shadows（阴影）
edge antialiasing（抗锯齿）
group opacity（不透明）
so if you turn off opaque&shadows and turn on rasterise it will be quicker.you will feel the difference. but still slow the application.